# STS slow build when loading xyz-context.xml files

Tags: eclipse, spring

i recently started using STS on a 64 bit Windows machine. Often when i "clean" my project STS gets unresponsive or just takes minutes to build while loading context.xml. files.
How can I fix this?  Is it looking for resources on the web and waiting for timeouts.?

EDIT: I noticed that during the build process my network usage goes up. Not sure yet what is going on there...

EDIT: Possibly STS is loading all of the referenced springsource XSD files for XML validation?`If so, how can I disable this validation (apart from copying the files and referencing them locally, of course)? I've already tried disabling all of the Preferences related to "Validation" in STS - to no avail.

Answer (score 3):

Often it is, because java is running out of free memory and need to run the garbage collector very often.

You can see the free memory in the bottom right corner of eclipse if you enable Window/Prefercences/General/"Show heap status".

If you can confirm that it is a memory problem, then you can increase the memory in `sts.ini` (-Xmx).

*It is said that the 64bit java version needs up to 1/3 more memory than the 32bit version. But I don't know if this rumour is right or not.*

Comment: Thanks Ralph, a useful tip. I activated it. But it seems my problem is most likely related to a network connection, possibly loading remote spring xsd files for xml validation...